# Select date and time using string case

Tags: string-manipulation

I did the following code to get data from a list:

```
Partition[Flatten[StringCases[Flatten[del2], {__ ~~ ":" ~~ _ ~~ ($1___) ..} -> { $1}, Infinity], 2], 23]
```

Where del2 is a list of strings data:

```
{{"report_id: 72431", "city: Duque de Caxias", "state: Rio de Janeiro", "country: BR", "report_date_local: 2015-10-16 02:58:00", "report_date_utc: 2015-10-16 05:58:00", "timezone: BRT", "latitude: -22.754167", "longitude: -43.294351", "altitude: 6.669782", "moving_direction: UpLeftToDownRight", "magnitude: -18.00", "duration: 1.50", "looking_azimuth: 218.67000", "initial_azimuth: 203.16000", "initial_altitude: 30", "final_azimuth: 256.93000", "final_altitude: 24", "rating: 1", "record_date: 2015-10-16 15:29:33", "first_name: MAycon", "last_name: S", "descent_angle: 94.00"}, {"report_id: 72452", "city: Rio de Janeiro", "state: Rio de Janeiro", "country: BR", "report_date_local: 2015-10-16 02:01:00", "report_date_utc: 2015-10-16 05:01:00", "timezone: BRT", "latitude: -22.961191", "longitude: -43.165434", "altitude: 21.876047", "moving_direction: DownLeftToUpRight", "magnitude: -27.00", "duration: 7.50", "looking_azimuth: 349.94000", "initial_azimuth: 253.72000", "initial_altitude: 47", "final_azimuth: 355.90000", "final_altitude: 59", "rating: 1", "record_date: 2015-10-16 20:09:27", "first_name: Petula ", "last_name: P", "descent_angle: 52.00"},....}
```

And the final result is the parameters of each sublists:

```
{{"72431", "Duque de Caxias", "Rio de Janeiro", "BR", "0", "0", "BRT", "-22.754167", "-43.294351", "6.669782", "UpLeftToDownRight", "-18.00", "1.50", "218.67000", "203.16000", "30", "256.93000", "24", "1", "3", "MAycon", "S", "94.00"}, {"72452", "Rio de Janeiro", "Rio de Janeiro", "BR", "0", "0", "BRT", "-22.961191", "-43.165434", "21.876047", "DownLeftToUpRight", "-27.00", "7.50", "349.94000", "253.72000", "47", "355.90000", "59", "1", "7", "Petula ", "P", "52.00"},.....}
```

But  my code gets only the final digits of the each substrings date and hours

(..,"_date_local:.....", "date_utc:..........",...,"record_date:...",... )

How can I improve this code to include date and hour correctly in the final list?

Comment: `list /. s_String :> Last[StringSplit[s, ": "]]`?

Comment: Perfect. Simple, clean and incredible short. Thank you J.M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To settle this: one merely needs to use `": "` as a unique delimiter for `StringSplit[]`.

```
list /. s_String :> Last[StringSplit[s, ": "]]
```